# How do I condense my JS redirect into a function that's faster for browsers to execute?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have redirects to implement but they look messy and I'm hoping there is a way to condense it to increase the speed of execution. Basically I need multiple pages redirecting to the same URL. This is what I have so far (there are 5 originating pages to include):

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("www.originalwebs1.com") >= 0){
window.location.replace("www.alternatewebs.com");
}

if(document.URL.indexOf("www.originalwebs2.com") >= 0){
window.location.replace("www.alternatewebs.com");
}

if(document.URL.indexOf("www.originalwebs3.com") >= 0){
window.location.replace("www.alternatewebs.com");
}
```

Please note this will be injected to the site using Monetate.

Thanks all.

Comment: `if(/originalwebs[123].com/.test(window.location.host)) { ...}`

Comment: The websites here are made up - the originalwebs will be totally different paths in the URL when used in real life.

Comment: @Rajesh: Your assumption that originalwebs* will be format always is wrong.

Comment: Your are assuming that all URLs will have common prefix `originalwebs` and only last character is supposed to be digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fasted way I can think of.

Using the [Array.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_indexof_array) you can easily do. You can write code such that `Array: URLs` in the code will be added with `Monetate`. Here is sample code:

```
function redirect(URL){
var URLs = ["www.originalwebs1.com", "www.originalwebs2.com", "www.originalwebs3.com"]; 


if(URLs.indexOf(URL)>-1)
   {
    window.location.replace("www.alternatewebs.com");
   }
}
```

Comment: Please suggest faster than this. I am assuming that he is receiving/adding new enteries to the Array URLs and getting indexOf.

You can't use regex here as you don't know the URL format beforehand.
Hence, you need to traverse once through all the URLs .

Comment: 1. hashmap will take more space in DS implementation
2. Objective is fastest way.
3. While storing hashmap, it will have more time-complexity to insert.

Hashmap is only fasted when your dictionary is already created and static. Insertion and then searching in hashmap can be slow when done one very small sample size.

Comment: Lets not debate over it. By no means, I'm saying your answer is wrong. Its perfectly correct. But the word *fastest* can be incorrect. Note *can* as it will depend on usage. If you have a large and dynamic array, `indexOf` can be expensive.

Comment: @Rajesh: Correct, but OP has mentioned that there can be 5 original URLs.. Lets close this.

Comment: This worked after adding `redirect(window.location.href);` to the end of the string to call the function. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
var webs = ["website1.com", "website2.com", "website3.com"];
var url = "website2.com";

for (i = 0; i < webs.length; i++) {
  if (url == webs[i]) {
    // navigate
  }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you choose to condense your code, you should start by looking at the common/redundant code. In your case:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf() >= 0){
  window.location.replace("www.alternatewebs.com");
}
```

---

You can use options like switch case:

```js
switch (window.location.host) {
  case 'originalwebs1.com':
  case 'originalwebs2.com':
  case 'originalwebs3.com':
    window.location.replace("www.alternatewebs.com");
    break;
}
```

---

Or you can create a hashMap which will have values combination:

```js
var hashMap = {
  'originalwebs1.com': "www.alternatewebs.com",
  'originalwebs2.com': "www.alternatewebs1.com",
  'originalwebs3.com': "www.alternatewebs2.com",
}

var url = hashMap[window.location.host];

if(url) {
  window.location.replace(url);
}
```

---

Or if the options are very similar that a regex can validate it, you can follow my comment:

> if(/originalwebs[123].com/.test(window.location.host)) { ...}

---

Which is the best way, would depend on your use-case. Based on input and output urls.

**Note:** Above answer denotes different ways to have same functionality but due to unclarity of input and output url, I have depicted possible options. If you feel anything is *improper/ unnecessary/ incorrect*, please share your feedback along with your vote.

Have a good day!